# Как называется технология для отображения незагруженного web-компонента?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, reactjs

Когда-то натыкался на статью о библиотеке, которая при загрузке тяжелых страниц в тех местах, где будет отображен компонент, который еще грузится, ставит заглушки в виде серых областей. Пример такой загрузки на Youtube: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называется эта технология?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preloader, но конкретно для той что на картинке может быть свое название.
Вот например:
https://github.com/zalog/placeholder-loading